# Android application works fine in 3G but not with WIFI

Tags: android, android-wifi, 3g

This my play video app
It works fine in 3G but it forces close via WIFI
this is the code:

```
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.MediaController;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class Video extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_video);

        String path="http://commonsware.com/misc/test2.3gp";


        Uri uri=Uri.parse(path);
        MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);

        VideoView video=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        mc.setAnchorView(video);
        mc.setMediaPlayer(video);
        video.setMediaController(mc);
        video.setVideoURI(uri);
        video.start();
    }

}
```

and this is the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

This is the logCat

```
03-25 09:25:27.019: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(20221): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
03-25 09:25:32.359: I/MediaPlayer(20221): uri is:http://commonsware.com/misc/test2.3gp
03-25 09:25:32.359: I/MediaPlayer(20221): path is null
03-25 09:25:32.359: D/MediaPlayer(20221): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
03-25 09:25:32.489: D/VideoView(20221): onMeasure()
03-25 09:25:32.489: I/VideoView(20221):     Setting size: 320x240
03-25 09:25:32.569: D/VideoView(20221): onMeasure()
03-25 09:25:32.569: I/VideoView(20221):     Setting size: 320x240
03-25 09:25:32.699: E/MediaPlayer(20221): error (1, -2147483648)
03-25 09:25:32.699: E/MediaPlayer(20221): Error (1,-2147483648)
03-25 09:25:32.699: D/VideoView(20221): Error: 1,-2147483648
```

In the screen apperas: "this video can´t be played"
Any clue??

Thank you very much

Comment: post your logcat output.

Comment: Sorry Anup,I´ve already added it

Comment: @Ivan : Are you sure your wifi network is able to route the request to the commonsware server? Have you tried just using your device browser to connect to `http://commonsware.com/`?

Comment: I don't see any problem with the code. Check if your wifi is able to access the internet and connect to the path you have mentioned. Just connect to wifi and open the url in your browser and see if it works.

Comment: I´m sorry I didn´t pass the firewall. It works now. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a mistake, via wifi I have to pass a firewall and I forgot to do it in that device, it was my fail.

Thanks to everybody